# Change password for default keyring in Ubuntu 9.04 Netbook Remix

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, ubuntu-netbook-remix

Where can I change the password for the default keyring?  It still wants to use my old password to unlock wireless connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps to change the default keyring password:

1. Go to *Accessories -> Password and
   Encryption Keys*
2. Click on the *Passwords* tab
3. Right click on *Passwords: default* (or maybe it says *Passwords: login*)
4. Select *Change Password*
5. Enter the old password (probably the one you entered on installation of Ubuntu)
6. Enter the new password you want, and enter it again for confirmation
7. Click *Change*

And you're done!

Comment: One more information: *Accessories* is a submenu in the *Applications* menu.