# Change password for default keyring in GalliumOS

Tags: linux, password-management, xfce, chromebook

A friend of mine has installed [GalliumOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GalliumOS) onto his chromebook, but can't figure out how to set the password for his default keyring. We have found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/58691/change-password-for-default-keyring-in-ubuntu-9-04-netbook-remix), but there is nothing resembling *passwords* under Accessories in GalliumOS, and a search through the menu system doesn't seem to get us anywhere.

How do we set the password for the default keyring?

Answer (score 0):

We found the answer in another forum, but I am posting it here for posterity:

`rm -f $HOME/.local/share/keyrings/*`

Then reopen your web browser and set the password.

Answer (score 0):

The application you are looking for is called [seahorse](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse). I just installed it in Gallium using the default XFCE session and it looks like it's working as expected. Using the app might be better than just deleting or moving the data files to another location.